# Will it be good idea to push images via websocket?

Tags: html, image, websocket

I need to develop a real time application... Just wondering will it be good idea to push images via websockets? Only advantage I can think of is it will reduce the number of HTTP request however disadvantage if i will have to encode it and then send it which means more data transmission.

Can someone list down the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

Advantages:

- You can generate the images on the fly in the (perhaps always running) server software. Note that this will not be a real advantage, since a always running server software could also serve http-data directly and generate it on-the-fly.

Disadvantages:

- No data will be cached. This is most ineffective when the client has to show/load the same image twice.
- You have to bother with encodings.
- You must somehow get the transfered data into the `img` which is only possible via the `data:`-scheme or a `canvas` (at least these are the only ways I can imagine), which is not very flexible (not supported by all browsers, length restrictions)
- The browser's functions to optimize the loading order can not be used.
- Mobile clients can not decide weather to load the data.

Further notice that there is no advantage in that less http-connections have to be set up, since http allows to keep connections alive (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html for details). This way the browser can use the keep-alive if it supports it and has not to use it, if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all the points. The major point i see is Browser cache but how about using local storage instead of cache?

Comment: What do you mean by local storage? On the user's hard disk? Is the data that big? Many big sites use a trick for many small images: They deliver all images in a single image file and select the shown part via css, could that be an option?

Comment: Yes local storage on user hard disk. But i cant use a big image because there are so many images users can search and filter. I was thinking to send images via web sockets and store them on local storage.. what do you say?

Comment: Do you mean some kind of advanced cookie mechanism intruduced in html5? I don't think this is a good idea, since there are some different implementations of different standards in different browsers and I wouldn't like to recode the whole thing for each browser (-version). I can just see no advantace compared with the mechanisms of the browser cache.

Comment: no not exactly cookie mechanism.. I mean local storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: :) Lets call it HTML5 Storage